# Thrift with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, thrift

I'm trying to compile Thrift and run it on Visual Studio 2010. The thing I did was to visit their wiki http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageCSharp and download the project.

However it seems to be using Visual Studio 2008. I've tried to search for another implementation however there doesn't seem to be one.

Is their a way to work around this so it can work with Visual Studio 2010? Is the project maybe outdated and won't have further updates in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the 2008 sln file in VS 2010. On first opening, it will tell you that it needs to upgrade the sln file to the latest version. Click next and let it upgrade. Then continue with the instructions from Thrift